# Overriding a large number of !default values with the @use rule in Sass/Scss

Tags: sass

I've got an SCSS module with a whole lot of overridable `!default` variables, and I'm trying to make use of it in a project using the new [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) rule instead of the to-be-deprecated `@import`. Overriding a large number of variables used to be pretty straightforward. As long as I imported my variables before importing the module they would take precedence over the `!default` values.

---

Now, if I try to `@use` the module in the global namespace like so:

```
$h1-font-size: 40px;

@use 'my-module' as *;
```

I get an error -  `SassError: This module and the new module both define a variable named "$h1-font-size".`

---

Apparently the proper way to do this is to use the `with` keyword like so

```
@use 'my-module' with (
    $h1-font-size: 40px
);
```

But now my `$h1-font-size` variable isn't available to other parts of my code. It's only scope is in overriding the value in the module. If I tried to assign it to something else, I'd get an Undefined variable error.

---

So that leaves me doing this

```
$h1-font-size: 40px;

@use 'my-module' with (
    $h1-font-size: $h1-font-size
);

.foo {
    font-size: $h1-font-size;
}
```

This is the exact effect I want - a variable that overrides my module and is still available for use elsewhere. However this syntax is cumbersome for passing a large number of overrides. If I want to pass say 30 overrides, I need 30 variable definitions and then 30 lines within the `with` block to explicitly pass in 30 values.

---

### Update / Edit

The answer from @Miriam Suzanne below makes it apparent I have oversimplified my use case for the purpose of asking a question.

Our shop has a set of mixins and base styles we use on many projects and I have been attempting to turn them into a reusable module to reduce the copy/pasting. Something like Bootstrap, with a lot of overridable `!default` values. Very much a work in progress, but the module itself can be seen here: [Derekstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@evanshunt/derekstrap).

This module is being developed in tandem with the first project we're actually using this on. The `!default` values are all in the module, and I would like to override them in my project.

Right now I have code in my `main.scss` (the primary entry point for stylesheets) that looks like this.

```
$base-font-family: 'Raleway', Tacoma, sans-serif;
$base-line-height: 1.8;

@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap/index' with (
    $base-font-family: $base-font-family,
    $base-line-height: $base-line-height
);
```

I like to structure my scss files pretty granularly so ideally those variables would actually live in another file, and also be available to other files in the project.

If I do something like the following, where both my variables file and the module have a `$base-font-family` variable defined, it compiles but by variables don't override the module.

```
@use 'variables' as *;
@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap/index' as *;
```

I suspect at this point the answer is that I need to add `@use` and/or `@forward` statements to my variables file(s), but it's breaking my brain a bit to figure out if I'll be able to successfully override different parts of the module in different parts of my project code. The suggestion above of just one variables file is also a bit of a simplification. How important will the order of the `@use` statements in my `main.scss` become if I am modifying the same namespace across the files being `@use`d?

---

I get the purpose of scoping and passing values explicitly but I'd love some sort of shorthand or trick to accomplish this without writing so much extra code. As mentioned in my Sass [feature request ticket](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2889) I was hoping for a simple shorthand for passing one context into another like:

```
@use 'variables' as variables;
@use 'module' with variables;
```

This doesn't seem possible and I'm wondering if I need to completely rethink the way I structure SCSS files to achieve what I want. What can I do here?

Comment: dave, did you ever find a good solution for this? I am in the same boat. I did find that creating my own variables file with @forward to bundle with({one by one add my variables}) did work. However, it is still cumbersome and hacky'ish in my opinion. You still have to make sure you also declare it first before you include the other bundle. Which can make it difficult for others to use it. While Miriam did a great job explaining things I feel like there is still something missing. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you mean when you say the variable "isn't available to other parts of my code". The entire purpose of `@use` is to make those variables available – *but inside a namespace*. So you can do:

```
@use 'module' with (
    $h1-font-size: 40px
);

.foo {
    font-size: module.$h1-font-size;
}
```

or remove the namespace using `as *`:

```
@use 'module' as * with (
    $h1-font-size: 40px
);

.foo {
    font-size: $h1-font-size;
}
```

or forward the module while also adding configuration, to use in other files:

```
@forward 'module' with (
    $h1-font-size: 40px !default
);
```

or both at once:

```
@forward 'module' with (
    $h1-font-size: 40px !default
);

@use 'module';

.foo {
    font-size: module.$h1-font-size;
}
```

I think that likely covers all the potential use-cases you might have for defining the same variable again?

---

In response to updates on the question…

Using the module syntax means that there is *no global scope across files*. That means *every individual file* needs to explicitly `@use` any-and-all required modules for that file. That means:

- You will need to `@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap/index'` (or similar) at the top of every single file that should have access to Derekstrap mixins, variables, or functions
- Since `index` files are imported automatically, and default namespaces are generated based on the path, I'd probably `@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap'` instead…
- Namespaces are always local to the importing file, so you can `@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap'` in one place (creating a `derekstrap` namespace), and `@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap' as *` in another (removing the namespace), and still `@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap' as derek` in a third place.

The goal of `!default` "configurable" variables is that they can be pre-configured before any compilation. That has to happen "first time" a module is used. If you want to do that in a file all to itself, you can:

```
// _config.scss
@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap' with (
  $h1-font-size: 40px,
);

// main.scss
@use 'config'; // keep this path first...
@use 'anything-else';

// _anything-else.scss
@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap';
// derekstrap.$h1-font-size will already be configured by config.scss
```

Those values can only be pre-configured once - meaning the compilation will *start* with the configuration value. But you can update those variables any time in any file:

```
// _anything-else.scss
@use '~@evanshunt/derekstrap';

derekstrap.$h1-font-size: 32px;
// The $h1-font-size now has a value of 32px
// for any file to uses derekstrap later in the compilation
```

On my site, I use a combination of both approaches - just inside my one color config file:

https://github.com/mirisuzanne/mia/blob/main/src/scss/config/_color.scss

I have the `@use … with` pattern for configuring `cascading-color-systems`, but I also use `accoutrement` tools without configuration, and then override `tools.$colors`.

You can get quite a bit more complex by adding in layers of forwarding, but this should get you started. Remember:

- The variable `$h1-font-size` exists inside the `'~@evanshunt/derekstrap'` module.
- That module can used multiple times, and given a different namespace each time. The module is always the same module, but namespaces are local.
- Pre-compile "Configuration" can only happen the first time a module is used, but you can continue to override those variables at any time.

Much like before, there is only one Derekstrap `$h1-font-size` variable, and it takes on different values over the course of compilation. what's *new* with modules is only that you need to explicitly `@use` Derekstrap in every file that wants access to that variable.

I understand it can take some getting used to, but in the end I've found my code is much more organized. You might want to set up a test project and play around, until the mental model makes more sense.

Comment: Hmmm... This does offer some possible ideas. I'm still trying to get my head into the new paradigm here. I think my examples above may have simplified away an important detail of my actual use case. I encountered this while having my variables actually defined in another file. Was looking to pull in the variables, pass them to module, and still have them available for use in subsequent styles. With two other files I've got two namespaces, and I can't merge them. I get the error about a duplicate variable definition, even if one is !default.

Comment: @dave Once you have configured the variables in `module` from one file, you can `@use 'module'` again in any number of files in order to access those configured variables. By combining `@forward` & `@use` you should have access to any variables you need, anywhere, with any desired namespace. Sorry, I still don't have a strong sense where the actual problem is, since the code you provided doesn't cover the use-case you're asking about. If you can paste a more specific example, I could give a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Miriame Suazzne, thanks for taking the time. I edited my question with a bit more elaboration on what I'm trying. I suspect the answer is some configuration in which I disperse my `@use` and `@forward` statements across many files instead of within my single point of entry main file. Curious as to how variables set to one namespace in one file will play in other files that use the same name space but don't necessarily `@use` or `@forward` each other but are both `@use`d by my main.scss.

Comment: @dave I made another attempt at describing things above. Hopefully that makes sense. There's no functional issue that I can see here - just a matter of you getting used to the new mental model, and playing around to be sure you understand it. There are still many ways to interact with, configure, pass-along, and update modules throughout your project -- it just takes a bit more careful architecture.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I very much like the new module feature, just trying to sort out the patterns for making use of it. I appreciate not having hidden dependencies. Configuring only once makes sense, even if it is not exactly what I was initially trying for. A `_config.scss` is the pattern I needed to put the pieces together.

Comment: That link no longer works, here is a commit where it exists: https://github.com/mirisuzanne/mia/blob/9a705932ff05676d8f07821f9687bb3fbec33816/src/scss/config/_color.scss